# Flutter fails to run Android

Tags: android, flutter

I have a flutter app which is building correctly the iOS version, but not the Android.
FOr the Android I get the error:

```
CameraPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
```

My pubspect.yaml has the following dependency

```
camera: ^0.5.7+2
```

This is my gradle.properties

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M

android.enableR8=true
```

Comment: Is it actually preventing the app to run? You should be able to just ignore that warning.

Comment: But I Cannot build the apk. I can run on emulator only

Comment: When you build the apk, what error are you getting?